# Pass a variable in an Xpath String

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have an xsl file which contains some xPath..

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:variable name="ref_num" select="ABCD"/>    

<xsl:template match="holiday">
    <fromPrice>
        <xsl:copy-of select="document('/file/to/path/in/documents/FILE1.xml',/)/dataroot/Tour/RefNo[.='ABHC']/preceding-sibling::AXL "/>
    </fromPrice>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**The Scenario..**
The xml file is returning the `<fromPrice>` values from the `FILE1.xml`(of which the value is coming from the `<AXL>` element) file correctly as follows:

**FILE1.xml**

```
<Tour>
    <Allocation>0</Allocation>
    <Available>16</Available>
    <AXL>4658</AXL>
    <ALO>2195</ALO>
    <RefNo>AABC</RefNo>
</Tour>
<Tour>
    <Allocation>0</Allocation>
    <Available>16</Available>
    <AXL>1295</AXL>
    <ALO>595</ALO>
    <RefNo>ATSS</RefNo>
</Tour>
```

**The problem:**
I wanted `$ref_num` to be passed in the xPath at the `"/RefNo[.='ABHC']"` so that `RefNo` contains the value `ABCD` for the variable `$ref_num`. That way, if `$ref_num` changes, I don't have to hard code the xPath at `"/RefNo[.='ABHC']"` again.

So far I tried the following: 
* `/RefNo[.=' "+$ref_num+ "']` and that didn't work.{Stylesheet error. Can't Compile}
* `/RefNo[.=' \"+$ref_num+ \"']` and that didn't work too.{Stylesheet error. Can't Compile} 
* `/RefNo[.='+$ref_num+']` and that didn't work too.{Stylesheet error. Can't Compile}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see where that would be a problem, just use the variable in the expression.

```
<xsl:variable name="ref_num" select="AABC" />
<xsl:variable name="filePath" select="'/file/to/path/in/documents/FILE1.xml'" />
<xsl:variable name="tours" select="document($filePath)/dataroot" />

<xsl:template match="holiday">
    <fromPrice>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$tours/Tour[RefNo = $ref_num]/AXL" />
    </fromPrice>
</xsl:template>
```

Hint: XPath expressions are not strings. This is not interpolation.

Comment: I figured!! I tried having the whole XPath as a variable and it output as a string. Ahhh this is nice !! Apreciate this solution !! It works !! @Tomalak